# Is it fine to use a derogatory word like Mleccha on this site?

Tags: discussion, support, etiquette, code-of-conduct

Only some time back I got to know about the word "Mleccha" and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mleccha) offers the following definition:

> Mleccha (from Vedic Sanskrit mlecchá, meaning "non-Vedic", "barbarian") is a Sanskrit term referring to foreign or **barbarous peoples** in ancient India, as contradistinguished from Aryas. Mleccha was used by the ancient Indians originally to indicate the **uncouth** and incomprehensible speech of foreigners and then extended to their unfamiliar behaviour, and also used as a **derogatory term in the sense of "impure" and/or "inferior" people**.
>
> The word Mleccha was commonly used for 'outer barbarians of whatever race or colour'.
>
> The Indians referred to all alien cultures and races that were less civilized in ancient times as 'Mleccha' or barbarians.

But on this site this term is used pretty unabashedly. For example, in chat:

> BTW, how are the **so-called mlecchas** so powerful? And we, the followers of Sanatana Dharma so weak? What went wrong?

Not taking names so not posting links to actual chat messages.

Same applies to the main site where "Mleccha Deshas" (foreign countries) is used in questions freely.

So my question is, is "Mleccha" safe to use on Hinduism.SE irrespective of the context or should we avoid using such derogatory terms as much as possible (excluding genuine questions) and edit out the word from all existing posts where it's been used with a bad connotation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the word "mleccha" considered offensive?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/how-is-the-word-mleccha-considered-offensive)

Comment: @sv. that one have no conclusion and this one have different angle

Comment: It didn't have a conclusion probably because users are divided on this. But definitely a duplicate

Comment: barbarous - this word would probably be too much on english translation... As known, some words are wrong in English when translated and would sound harsh.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti I disagree Mleccha was never supposed to be a polite word.

Comment: The word is used to describe non-Vedic people. Being non-Vedic is bad, so obviously it will have a negative connotation.

Comment: @Ikshvaku There are people who got Moksha even by being non vedic. So just like that we cannot say like that harsh. These are just users manual for life. just guidance. thats it!!!

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti Doesn't change the fact that they were mleccha.

Comment: @Ikshvaku the above point is for your word "being non vedic is bad".

Comment: The chat example is too old, Btw.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā old or new doesn't matter. If new examples are needed, they can be shown. What's offensive doesn't have an expiry date. The intention behind choosing example is to portray how it's used on this site and how the moderation is going on. New or old is not the matter of discussion here.

Comment: This is not a Hindu site but is a site about Hinduism. This word shouldn't be used for addressing/targeting foreign people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think we should use it. As we community have both professionals and learners. This more sounds like a word used by professionals to learners and other people who don't follow ancient Sanatana Dharma, in an offensive way. But we can't restrict anyone to not use it. We can just flag if the word is being used in offensive manner and explain the same to the mods.

And yes, we should edit all posts if it has been used in non-relative context of the post.

Comment: Also see example like this https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48869601#48869601 I am not sure why mods can't say anything here and how come it's acceptable.

Comment: It is acceptable until someone flags it.

Comment: @Mr_Green So even if a mod reads it first and finds it offensive, they should wait until someone flags it before taking action?

Comment: should we also tag posts which have the tag 'mythology' for scriptures because it is offensive to 'natives' ?

Comment: why it will be offensive if you tag a post as 'mythology' to anyone? I don't understand. I don't think I care much.