# Apparently the term 'Mleccha' is offensive to 'foreigners', but the term 'mythology' is not offensive to scriptures of 'natives'?

Tags: discussion

Mods, are you ever going to remove the mythology tag ?

It doesn't matter what the *ideal* replacement is - scriptures, sacred-texts, vedas, itihasa, purana, epics - are fine, and cover the gamut of non-fictional stories from the past.

The wannabe-secular-gora-validation-seeking-mentality is strong with some users on this site.. Still, I'll play along - both [christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) and [islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) have the tag mythology, but guess the number of questions in those tags ? 4. Exactly Four each. Linked above.

Whereas most of our scriptures, Itihasa and Purana are tagged as mythology. Guess how many questions ? [1,339](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology)

To the woke crowd here, this is equivalent to tagging questions related to the Bible and Koran as 'mythology'.

While regular users on this site might know what the tag 'mythology' refers to, this site is not just for users, is it? It's for the general public mainly. And the overwhelmingly common definition of the word 'mythology' includes the meaning 'false' or 'believed to be fiction'.

In cases where there is genuine doubt about hear-say, we can use the term 'folklore', but *mythology* has to go - if the mods have it in them, that is.

Comment: I will be honest. When I first came to this site I thought the tag mythology meant that site is open to any spin on our epics, even Devadutt Pattnaik style  (No offense to those who believe his words). It is only after I saw Keshav's post on mythology tag and the repeated focus of this site on getting answers from genuine sources were my thoughts corrected . My request to mods is that mythology tag be done away because both in outside world and on this site, the mythology is coming across as a  euphemism for fiction aka Harry Potter type

Comment: @Carmensandiego, we can focus on getting genuine sources AND still not call it mythology.

Comment: As I told before, I don't think this tag will ever be removed. We have consensus to remove for some time now but still its not removed@ram

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New Community Consensus on use of Mythology Tag](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/new-community-consensus-on-use-of-mythology-tag)

Comment: @sv knowledge and action are two different things.

Comment: "The wannabe-secular-gora-validation-seeking-mentality is strong with some users on this site"  is a serious violation of site decorum.

Answer (score 6):

I agree this tag should be burned. This is not good for our site.

We are not **discussing any myth stuff here**. It is all from **Scriptural references**. If anyone wants to start a mythology post, there is whole **[Mythology.SE](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/)** where you can ask the same **but not here**.

I disagree with [my previous comment](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/is-it-fine-to-use-a-derogatory-word-like-mleccha-on-this-site/1727#comment8392_1727https://). It does feel offensive to the mass number of users on this site.

**Conclusion:**

We should avoid using both the word Mleccha and the mythology tag. Let's be respectful to each other.

**[Update from mod (March 2020)](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1847/93)**

> Yes, if we consider top voted answers including the accepted one, it seems community is agree with purge of mythology tag. In August 2019 I proposed another way but finally we (mods) concluded to remove the tag completely but community moderators can't purge a tag completely, it needs Community Managers or probably developers to accomplish the task.
>
> 3 Years ago In Aug 2019 we had discussed with other mods and also pinged CMs if we can remove the tag completely. We first need to retag all those questions which are tagged only with mythology. We edited some questions to apply this fix but some questions couldn't get fixed and hence we didn't accomplish the task of purging the tag. Anyway, we will again try to resolve this issue soon.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105345/discussion-on-answer-by-mr-green-apparently-the-term-mleccha-is-offensive-to).