# It should not be allowed to call contemporary eminent Western Sanskrit scholars "Mlecchas"

Tags: discussion

[How can the integrity of a Vedic verse be verified?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38346/how-can-the-integrity-of-a-vedic-verse-be-verified)

> Mlecchas shouldn't read the Vedas let alone comment on what is part of it or not. – Ikshvaku

wiki:

> Mleccha (from Vedic Sanskrit mlecchá, meaning "non-Vedic", "barbarian") is a Sanskrit term referring to foreign or barbarous peoples in ancient India, as contradistinguished from Aryas. Mleccha was used by the ancient Indians originally to indicate the uncouth and incomprehensible speech of foreigners and then extended to their unfamiliar behaviour, and also used as a derogatory term in the sense of "impure" and/or "inferior" people.
>
> The word Mleccha was commonly used for 'outer barbarians of whatever race or colour'.[1][2]
>
> The Indians referred to all alien cultures and races that were less civilized in ancient times as 'Mleccha'[3] or barbarians. Among the tribes termed Mlechcha were Sakas, Hunas, Yavanas, Kambojas, Pahlavas, Bahlikas and Rishikas.[4] The Amarakosha described the Kiratas, Khasas and Pulindas as the Mleccha-jatis. Indo-Greeks, Scythians,[5] and Kushanas[6] were also mlecchas.[7]

It is pure racism to call contemporary eminent European and American Sanskrit scholars by this word.

The use of this word, except in citations of scripture **seriously** lowers the tone of this board.

and it is so ironic that posters living in a "Mleccha" desha using a "Mleccha" language are badmouthing "Mlecchas".

this is not a duplicate of [Is it fine to use a derogatory word like Mleccha on this site?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/is-it-fine-to-use-a-derogatory-word-like-mleccha-on-this-site)

The word can be cited if it occurs in scripture. It cannot be applied to contemporary people - Hinduism has nothing to say as to who is or is not a mleccha today.

This question is not a duplicate of the other question that asks about the usage of the word in all cases.

Comment: According to [one mod](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/is-it-fine-to-use-derogatry-word-like-mleccha-on-this-site?r=SearchResults#comment7874_1715) it's offensive and should not be used on this site to refer to foreigners/westerners in a derogatory sense. But not sure why it's not enforced.

Comment: @sv. It has already been enforced by the community (_from the link answer you mentioned above_). I don't think we should wait for mod for everything. Marking this post as duplicate and flagging that comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it fine to use derogatry word like Mleccha on this site?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/is-it-fine-to-use-derogatry-word-like-mleccha-on-this-site)

Comment: @Mr_Green Your answer and the votes it received means nothing unless mods acknowledge the problem and enforce the code of conduct. I think there maybe a disagreement among mods themselves on the use of the word 'mlecchas' in a derogatory sense - look at the upvotes [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1598) post has received. No comment from any of the mods on that post. Remember that Hindu scripture itself sanctions such derogatory usage so there lies the problem. Some users want to continue using the term in a disparaging manner while others want to follow the SE CoC.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by mods should acknowledge? I thought this is purely community driven site where we make the rules and mods are just moderators. I hope this is how it is..

Comment: If I understand correctly, mods are not updating the CoC, which they should do if the community has concluded something. If this is the case then this should be discussed in a separate post to fix this ASAP.

Comment: @Mr_Green 'I thought this is purely community driven site where we make the rules and mods are just moderators.' - yes, but how abusive/unfriendly flags are handled depends on the site policy. When mods do not acknowledge the policy or different mods have different ideas about the policy, some flags will be rejected. Implementation of a policy ultimately comes down to a moderator handling a flag. Hope you already know this.

Comment: Mods should not implement their own ideas or do as they like, imo. They should obey the community guidelines and if they don't believe it they should discuss the same and the community will decide with votes that it is good or not. Community stands first not mods. Please do call out in a new discussion post if mods are not following community concluded scope (I am not much active here).

Comment: I am actually interested in knowing who comes under "eminent western scholars". Given that this site is about Hindu religion , do we need "secular" interpretation  of scriptures  ( western or not) as mentioned in the answer on main site.  If so, then it is just a matter of time that likes of Wendy Donniger and company will be frequenting here

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I couldn't agree more. Some users seem to think because public figures aren't registered users on SE, the [Code of Coduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct) doesn't apply to them and they can say whatever they want about them. But there's a specific MSE post on how to treat authors and other public figures on SE sites irrespective of their ideologies:

> [Does the Be Nice policy require SE users to "be nice" to people who are not SE users (e.g. public figures)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286082)

**Bottom line**: The SE Code of Conduct applies to everyone, not just SE users.

---

BTW, the first comment under your answer appears to have been deleted now.

The other comment which also made disparaging remarks on some scholars appears to have been edited by the mods.

Comment: *"The SE Code of Conduct applies to everyone"* - Correct ! *'Everyone'* includes Rishis who wrote ancient/traditional scriptures. If anyone is condescending, dishonestly & biased-ly suspicious, and casts aspersions on either their intellect or intent, then they lose the right to be treated politely. So if a public figure ("historian"); throws-the-first-stone against another public figure (Rishi), then the gloves are off.

Comment: A historian (or a user quoting a historian) respectfully disagreeing with an acharya or rishi, on reality and the nature of things, doesn't break the CoC. This is a secular site about Hinduism, not 'by Hindus, for Hindus'. Read [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21) answer. 'then they lose the right to be treated politely', 'then the gloves are off' - you can propose this new policy on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) and see how far it flies.

Comment: *"respectfully disagreeing with an acharya or rishi"* - your definition of *respectful* may not match that of others. Addressing someone as 'you' is generally not disrespectful. But if you address a highly respected figure as 'you' instead of 'Thou', that is considered disrespect by those who respect that figure, and thus, you have already broken the CoC. The "nice" in 'Be nice' - is not a universal barometer. Even mere judges demand to be called 'honor/lord', and carry contempt proceedings for breaking that rule. While Rishis don't demand it, their followers do. What *seems* innocuous to you

Comment: maybe inflammatory to others. Let me point you to this [classic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGHPd.jpg). You might think it is 'respectful disagreeing'. You might even say 'it's a comic, there is creative liberty, freedom of speech blah blah'. 
Well, then we will retort with whatever we feel to be respectful disagreeing, creative liberty and freedom of speech. Btw, I personally do think that comic is funny. But only because I personally know jyotisha is authentic in predicting major life events with just a piece of paper and no other info. But other users of this site most likely won't.