# Is this site promoting a culture of bullying new users?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, new-users, code-of-conduct

> Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Please don’t spread false information about Hinduism. They maybe your views, but the various answers have clarified to the contrary and have been accepted and voted by users. If you’re here to learn and contribute knowledge in an effective way you are welcome. Else **please do not spread rubbish on this site.** – Archit [22 hours ago](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8981/feminists-claim-that-the-vedas-ramayana-and-mahabharata-were-written-by-male-w/40757#comment127990_40757)
>
> > "Welcome!" "Don't spread rubbish on this site" what a pure hearted and warm welcome. – Raaj Vyavastha [18 hours ago](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8981/feminists-claim-that-the-vedas-ramayana-and-mahabharata-were-written-by-male-w/40757#comment127996_40757)
>
> **Just wondering if this is your real name?** Moreover we already know that many smritis and other texts have such statements against women and shudra – Rakesh Joshi [11 hours ago](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17797/why-do-sanyasa-scriptures-degrade-women/40769?noredirect=1#comment128018_40769)
>
> **You aren't able to write names properly. What to expect on your knowledge of shastras.** – Rakesh Joshi [11 hours ago](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17797/why-do-sanyasa-scriptures-degrade-women/40769?noredirect=1#comment128020_40769)
>
> **You seem new to Hinduism. Let's have a debate soon.** Can you quote similar quotes from valmiki ramayana also? – Rakesh Joshi [yesterday](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18962/why-devi-bhagavata-purana-being-a-purana-for-feminine-deity-insults-women/40752#comment127985_40752)

Why are these comments being [upvoted](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54678054#54678054)?

It appears some mods have already read these comments and I'm surprised why they haven't already deleted/edited these. Are they waiting for enough users to feel offended and flag them before acting on them?

Comment: Not a mod, but I [pinged](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54672088) Archit in the chat yesterday and asked them not to use those words. But I didn't see Rakesh's comment. I hope my comment on that post weren't rude :)

Comment: more examples of bullying of new site users in the comments under this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40793/8149). Moderators appear to be happy for this form of comment privilege abuse on this site to exist. When pressed via flagging the moderators leave it at deleting abusive comments, which falls far short of how such matters are dealt with on other SE sites. Repeat offenders need to have a cool-off period imposed on them. Not holding my breath though.

Comment: @iruvar, correct. i agree. when people abuse scriptures, they must be warned, flagged, and repeat offenders must be cooled off.

Comment: @iruvar Not sure if it will be of much use but there's an option to report a Code of Conduct violation on the [Contact Us](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/contact) page. If enough people report SE staff may take notice.

Comment: Is this site promoting a culture of bullying new **users**?  -- I don't think that is the case. You have collected evidence of what happened with only one user. It is not happening with other new users. It is unfortunate though that the new user decided to delete his account. But from what I have read from his comments he was not someone that can be bullied. He was very aggressive despite being a newbie on the site. @sv.

Comment: "I don't think that is the case" - read the previous comment by another user. He too saw it under another question. Comments were flagged & edited/deleted. We all know who these users are. They think SE rules don't apply to them and have the protection of mods. @Rickross

Comment: @Rickross, as I've alluded to in my previous comment the mods are themselves at fault here - by diligently cleaning up after these malefactors without taking them to task for their excesses they bury the evidence and embolden them further - hard to see this as anything other than complicit behaviour. Given this appears to be the way of things on HSE and that a site user's options for recourse are slim to none when the lunatics themselves are running the asylum, I'm saying all this just to set the record straight.

Comment: @iruvar 'anything other than complicit behaviour' - FYI, check the votes on [this meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/it-should-not-be-allowed-to-call-contemporary-eminent-western-sanskrit-scholars). Not a single answer or comment by a mod clarifying their stand on this issue.

Comment: @iruvar [Another post from last year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0r1M.jpg). Downvoted and deleted.

Comment: wow@sv talk about shooting the messenger. Those comments you've linked are way beyond the pale. Maybe the thing to do is to categorically not bother with HSE meta and instead, report straight up to to the main SE meta the next time you run into such egregious CoC violations. _That_ should suffice to stir the pot in these days of heightened sensitivities around racial prejudice. If sufficiently roused the main SE mods may take it upon themselves to salvage evidence from database backups and punish wrongdoers despite HSE mods having swept it under the carpet via deletion. One can dream....

Comment: and BTW, those _in flagrante_ screenshots you're putting away will serve nicely to build a case, way to go.